# what is the android exception that best fits this scenario?

Tags: android, exception

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> apps = 
    pm.queryIntentActivities(viewDocIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (apps.size() > 0)
    context.startActivity(viewDocIntent);
else
    throw new ... SOMETHING
```

Which exception would you think should be thrown if the resulting list is empty?

Comment: How about a dialog box?! What's the context here?

Comment: it is passed as a parameter to a helper class that handles my files, I did that so I could use polymorphism depending if they are saving to internal or external memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ActivityNotFoundException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html).